# How to get sum of the children nodes on every level in an hierarchical tree?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

I have table "A" with hierarchical data like this:

```
create table dictionary_a
(
  id number not null,
  parent_id number,
  c_name varchar2(50),
  constraint pk_dictionary primary key (id),
  constraint fk_dictionary foreign key (parent_id) references dictionary_a (id)
);
```

```
id parent_id c_name
1            name1
2  1         name2
3  1         name3
4  3         name4
5  3         name5
6  2         name6
7  6         name7
...
```

(actual hierarchical data table has 7 levels, but this is subject to change)

And table "B" with data i need to sum up:

```
create table numeric_data
(
  dict_id number not null,
  n_sum number,
  constraint fk_numeric_data foreign key (dict_id) references dictionary_a (id)
);
```

```
dict_id n_sum
1       36.0
2       20.0
3       16.0
4       10.5
5       5.5
7       20.0
...
```

Note that higher level nodes also have sums tied to them.

I need to get the sum of all child nodes at each level and compare them with the actual data from the column n_sum (this column is populated by users and my job is to find all the inconsistencies):

```
dict_id n_sum actual_sum c_name
1       36.0  36.0       name1
2       20.0  20.0       name2
3       16.0  16.0       name3
4       10.5  10.5       name4
5       5.5   5.5        name5
6             20.0       name6
7       20.0  20.0       name7
```

I searched Internet, but what I could find was very closely related to specific problems, no general solution.

Test data:

```
insert into dictionary_a (ID, PARENT_ID, C_NAME)
values (1, null, 'Department 1');

insert into dictionary_a (ID, PARENT_ID, C_NAME)
values (2, 1, 'Department 2');

insert into dictionary_a (ID, PARENT_ID, C_NAME)
values (3, 1, 'Department 3');

insert into dictionary_a (ID, PARENT_ID, C_NAME)
values (4, 3, 'Department 4');

insert into dictionary_a (ID, PARENT_ID, C_NAME)
values (5, 3, 'Department 5');

insert into dictionary_a (ID, PARENT_ID, C_NAME)
values (6, 2, 'Department 6');

insert into dictionary_a (ID, PARENT_ID, C_NAME)
values (7, 6, 'Department 7');

insert into numeric_data (DICT_ID, N_SUM)
values (1, 36);

insert into numeric_data (DICT_ID, N_SUM)
values (2, 20);

insert into numeric_data (DICT_ID, N_SUM)
values (3, 16);

insert into numeric_data (DICT_ID, N_SUM)
values (4, 10.5);

insert into numeric_data (DICT_ID, N_SUM)
values (5, 5.5);

insert into numeric_data (DICT_ID, N_SUM)
values (7, 20);

commit;
```

I am working on Oracle 18c.

Comment: You would do better to generate non-random data and to include your expected output. You also say you want to "compare them with the actual data from the column n_sum" however, there is no other column to sum that contains numeric data.

Comment: You are right. Is it ok if I edit it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an outer join between your tables:

```
select da.id, da.parent_id, da.c_name, coalesce(nd.n_sum, 0) as n_sum
from dictionary_a da
left join numeric_data nd on nd.dict_id = da.id;
```

and then use that as a source for a hierarchical query, tracking the root ID, name and quantity:

```
select id,
  parent_id,
  n_sum,
  connect_by_root id as root_id,
  connect_by_root n_sum as root_n_sum,
  connect_by_root c_name as root_c_name,
  connect_by_isleaf as isleaf
from (
  select da.id, da.parent_id, da.c_name, coalesce(nd.n_sum, 0) as n_sum
  from dictionary_a da
  left join numeric_data nd on nd.dict_id = da.id
)
connect by parent_id = prior id;
```

and then sum the leaf nodes to get the values you seem to want:

```
with cte as (
  select id,
    parent_id,
    n_sum,
    connect_by_root id as root_id,
    connect_by_root n_sum as root_n_sum,
    connect_by_root c_name as root_c_name,
    connect_by_isleaf as isleaf
  from (
    select da.id, da.parent_id, da.c_name, coalesce(nd.n_sum, 0) as n_sum
    from dictionary_a da
    left join numeric_data nd on nd.dict_id = da.id
  )
  connect by parent_id = prior id
)
select root_id as dict_id,
  root_n_sum as n_sum,
  sum(n_sum) as actual_sum,
  root_c_name as c_name
from cte
where isleaf = 1
group by root_id, root_n_sum, root_c_name
order by root_id;
```

Which with your explicit sample data gives:

| DICT_ID | N_SUM | ACTUAL_SUM | C_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 36 | 36 | name1 |
| 2 | 20 | 20 | name2 |
| 3 | 16 | 16 | name3 |
| 4 | 10.5 | 10.5 | name4 |
| 5 | 5.5 | 5.5 | name5 |
| 6 | 0 | 20 | name6 |
| 7 | 20 | 20 | name7 |

I've included `coalesce(nv.n_sum, 0)` so the 'original' `n_sum` value for ID 6 shows as zero rather than null, which your example doesn't have; it will show null if you just remove the coalesce, but including it means you can add a simple

```
having root_n_sum != sum(n_sum)
```

clause to only see the discrepancies. That clause just becomes more complicated if you leave nulls alone, but it might be preferable:

```
with cte as (
  select id,
    parent_id,
    n_sum,
    connect_by_root id as root_id,
    connect_by_root n_sum as root_n_sum,
    connect_by_root c_name as root_c_name,
    connect_by_isleaf as isleaf
  from (
    select da.id, da.parent_id, da.c_name, nd.n_sum
    from dictionary_a da
    left join numeric_data nd on nd.dict_id = da.id
  )
  connect by parent_id = prior id
)
select root_id as dict_id,
  root_n_sum as n_sum,
  sum(n_sum) as actual_sum,
  root_c_name as c_name
from cte
where isleaf = 1
group by root_id, root_n_sum, root_c_name
having (root_n_sum is null and sum(n_sum) is not null)
or (root_n_sum is not null and sum(n_sum) is null)
or root_n_sum != sum(n_sum)
order by root_id;
```

gives just:

| DICT_ID | N_SUM | ACTUAL_SUM | C_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | *null* | 20 | name6 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=39332db5ead10690f54e6c654c8c80e0)

Comment: This is exactly the solution I needed. Now it is obvious that I did not completely understand my original goal, and had insufficient knowledge in this matter. I edited original post and replaced test data with non-random one.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what your expected output is since you are generating random data; however, to solve the problem:

> I need to get the sum of all child nodes at each level

You can generate all the child nodes and use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` to keep a record of the root id of the hierarchy; then you can sum the values to get the total:

```sql
SELECT root_id,
       MAX(c_name),
       SUM(n_sum) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(id) AS root_id,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c_name) AS c_name,
         n.n_sum
  FROM   dictionary_a d
         INNER JOIN numeric_data n
         ON (d.id = n.dict_id)
  CONNECT BY PRIOR d.id = d.parent_id
)
GROUP BY root_id
ORDER BY root_id
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=af35da572ff240be80903d62a6596053)*

---

What you appear to want is not to sum all the child nodes but sum all the leaf nodes:

```sql
SELECT root_id,
       MAX(c_name) AS c_name,
       MAX(root_sum) As n_sum,
       SUM(n_sum) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS root_id,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT c_name AS c_name,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT n_sum AS root_sum,
         d.id,
         n.n_sum
  FROM   dictionary_a d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN numeric_data n
         ON (d.id = n.dict_id)
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  CONNECT BY PRIOR d.id = d.parent_id
)
GROUP BY root_id
ORDER BY root_id
```

Which, for your (non-random) sample data, outputs:

> | ROOT_ID | C_NAME | N_SUM | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | name1 | 36 | 36 |
> | 2 | name2 | 20 | 20 |
> | 3 | name3 | 16 | 16 |
> | 4 | name4 | 10.5 | 10.5 |
> | 5 | name5 | 5.5 | 5.5 |
> | 6 | name6 | *null* | 20 |
> | 7 | name7 | 20 | 20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ec52ddaba8647fa9f7487a5f92961475)*

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the sum of all child nodes at each level and compare them with the actual data from the column n_sum

There is **no need** to use **hierarchical query** if you only compares each parent with the sum of it's child:

So first outer join to your *number* table twice, once for `id` and once for `parent_id`.

The *sum of all child nodes* is as easy as an analytic  `SUM` over `parent_id`.

Than simple select all rows where the `child_sum` does not match the *node sum*.

```
WITH dt AS (
select da.id, da.parent_id, da.c_name, 
sum(nd.n_sum) OVER (partition by da.parent_id) as child_sum, 
ndp.n_sum as id_sum
from dictionary_a da
left join numeric_data nd on nd.dict_id = da.id
left join numeric_data ndp on ndp.dict_id = da.parent_id
WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL)
SELECT * FROM dt
WHERE nvl(child_sum,0) != nvl(id_sum,0)
```

As expected you get two problems

- for parent `2` the *child sum* is `null` but the node sum is 20  and
- for parent `6` the *child sum* is `20` but the node sum is `null`.